# Checking a field value for a home directory UNIX

Tags: unix, scripting

I am writing a script in Unix that will check the USER_ID field value to see if a home directory has been created. If the directory does not exist then I have to do the following:

1. Add the USER_ID as a valid user on the computer.
2. Replace certain values (the ones that are bolded) with the variables extracted from the following:
   *spiderman|Man|Spider|P|5|sun

lbanas|Banas|Kerry|S|5|mercury

dholder|Holder|David|S|5|venus

dives|Ives|David|W|5|earth

slambert|Lambert|Scott|S|5|mars

rtaylor|Taylor|Rich|S|5|jupiter

dtempleman|Templeman|Daniel|W|5|saturn

vtrimboli|Trimboli|Vincent|S|5|uranus

swalker|Walker|Steve|W|5|neptune

szemanek|Zemanek|Steven|W|5|pluto*

3. The PREFERRED_PASSWORD now needs to be encrypted and NOT plain text.  Fortunately LINUX has the ability to generate crypto keyed passwords by issuing this command (this -1 is a dash and number 1):

echo "P4ssw0rd" | openssl passwd -1 –stdin

The trick is to embed the encrypted password generator into the useradd command so you need to issue the openssl command and place it into a variable called ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD that will then be used as a parameter to the command:

FULL_NAME should be the value in the comment field, the ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD should replace the openssl password and the USER_ID should replace the user name (replaced values are bloded):
useradd –m –c **“Mike Paul”** –p **$(echo "P4ssw0rd"  | openssl passwd -1 -stdin)    mpaul**

4. place the value “spiderman created” into the MESSAGE variable

•   If the directory does exist place the value “spiderman already setup” into the MESSAGE variable

Comment: SO what's the issue and how far have you got?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help